# Remove EOL spaces of selection only if there are

Tags: vim, space, eol

How do I check if a selection has EOL spaces and remove them only if there are?

I need to remove the EOL spaces of a selection in order to do an other operation.
I would like to check if there are but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress errors in the `:substitute` command using the `e` flag.
So eckes' suggestion would become:

```
:'<,'>s/\ \+$//ge
```

Then any errors are ignored, and scripts are not interrupted. See `:help s_flags` for more information.

If you really want to check if there are trailing spaces you could try using something like

```
if matchstr(getline("."),'\s\+$') == ""
    " there is no trailing whitespace
else
    " there is some trailing whitespace
endif
```

Comment: Prince Goulash, I added the `e` flag but it still abort the next operation (I call a script after removing EOL spaces). The matchstr code only checks current line and not the entire selection.

Comment: I made a mistake. I checked it again. It works fine with the `e` flag. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While the selection is active (visual mode), simply type

```
:s/\ \+$//g
```

On the command line this will become

```
'<,'>s/\ \+$//g
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, mission complete.

If there are **no** trailing spaces, an error (E486) will be thrown but that's no problem.

---

**Edit 1:**
To be sure that you apply the substitution only where there really are occurrences of trailing white space, you could prefix the `:s` by [`:g`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:g):

```
:g/\ \+$/s/\ \+$//g
```

The trick of `:g` is that it applies the given command (`s/\ \+$//g`) only on those lines that match the given pattern.

---

**Edit 2:**
Things get even shorter, [as I recently learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804484/how-do-i-use-a-back-reference-in-the-cmd-executed-by-g):

```
:g/\s\+$/s///g
```

Comment: yes I know, but the error is the problem because it block the rest of the operation.

Comment: Thank you Eckes. I resolved it adding the `e` flag but your solution is nice as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to remove all white-space, the shortest command would probably be

```
:%s/\s*$//
```

<kbd>%</kbd> applies to entire buffer

<kbd>s</kbd> substitute

<kbd>/\s*$</kbd> match any whitespace followed by end-of-line

<kbd>//</kbd> replace matches with empty