# How do I use a back reference in the cmd executed by :g?

Tags: vim, global

When answering [Remove EOL spaces of selection only if there are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803579/remove-eol-spaces-of-selection-only-if-there-are), I noticed that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9803671/520162) is not really satisfying: the pattern `\ \+$` has to be typed twice:

- once for searching with `:g`
- once for replacing with `:s`

First thought was to simply use `g/\(\ \+$\)/s/\1//g` but this gives me an error about an invalid back reference ([`E65`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#E65)).

Is there a way to re-use the pattern used in [`:g`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:g) for the `[cmd]` being executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `\1`:

```
:g/ \+$/s///g
```

---

```
:g/pat/s//PAT/g
```

is same as:

```
:%s/pat/PAT/g
```